# How to create a form with its place holders animating?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a form similar to [SEND GRID](https://app.sendgrid.com/login) 
I am not sure what technology they have used. Google gave me some information on [MaterialsCSS](http://materializecss.com/). Is it good to use?

Can any one guide me on this?

Comment: if you inspect the soursecode for the login form, it is actually a `label` that is being moved rather than a `placeholder`. MaterialCSS is a great out-of-the-box option for what you're trying to do. It is quite robust, has good documentation, and is relatively easy to use.

Comment: thank you for the valuable comments haxxxton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS3 Will help you a lot !

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  vertical-align: top;
}
.input__field {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0.8em;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* for box shadows to show on iOS */
}
.input__field:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.input__label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 1em;
  width: 40%;
  color: #696969;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70.25%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.input__label-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.6em 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.graphic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: none;
}
.icon {
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 150%;
}
/* Nariko */

.input--nariko {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
.input__field--nariko {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0.35em;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #f18292;
}
.input__label--nariko {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #8E9191;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
.input__label--nariko::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 4px solid #9B9F9F;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -3px, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.input__label-content--nariko {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, color 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s, color 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.input__field--nariko:focus,
.input--filled .input__field--nariko {
  cursor: text;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.4s;
}
.input__field--nariko:focus + .input__label--nariko::before,
.input--filled .input__label--nariko::before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3.3em, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -3.3em, 0);
}
.input__field--nariko:focus + .input__label--nariko .input__label-content--nariko,
.input--filled .input__label-content--nariko {
  color: #6B6E6E;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3.3em, 0) scale3d(0.81, 0.81, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, -3.3em, 0) scale3d(0.81, 0.81, 1);
}
```

```html
<section class="content bgcolor-7">
  <h2>Input Custom Design</h2>
  <span class="input input--nariko">
     <input class="input__field input__field--nariko" type="text" id="input-20" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--nariko" for="input-20">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--nariko">Username</span>
  </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input input--nariko">
     <input class="input__field input__field--nariko" type="text" id="input-21" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--nariko" for="input-21">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--nariko">Website</span>
  </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input input--nariko">
     <input class="input__field input__field--nariko" type="text" id="input-22" />
     <label class="input__label input__label--nariko" for="input-22">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--nariko">Invitation Code</span>
  </label>
  </span>
</section>
```

Just HTML5, CSS3 and Modern browser Try This & edit as you can......

Comment: Thank You Abdul for the quick and detailed reply!

Comment: Thanks a lot @chuplu